# What is 'level' value in cvPyrSegmentation() in OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to find connected components using the Pyramid Segmentation function in OpenCV and VC++. What should I put as the level of the pyramid? Please explain (I've tried to make sense of the O'Reilly book)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html?highlight=cvpyrsegmentation#cvPyrSegmentation): *`level` – Maximum level of the pyramid for the segmentation.*
This means that the maximum value that `level` can get is the log-2 of the the minimum of the image width and height.
Realistically, you would reduce it by at least 2 or 3 as 4x4 or 8x8 images are typically not very informative...

Comment: thanks, your answer was practical - exactly what i was looking for. couldn't really grasp the theoretical aspect at short notice.